# How to pass information from click event on select to next input

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am fairly new to Blazor, and I am trying to pass information from one input to next based on click event.

For example, I have the following select element:

```
<select @onchange="(e => DoStuff(e.Value.ToString()))">
    @foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        <option value="@item.Id"> @item.Name </option>
    }
</select>
</div>
<div class="d-none d-sm-block col-2">
    <input type="number" @bind-value="ItemQuantity"/>
</div>
```

The idea is when a use clicks on on a selected item, I would like to send and capture that information in the next input (i.e., display `Item.Price`)

Currently, I am stuck on:

```
private void DoStuff(string e)
{
    isItemSelected = 1; 
    var Selected = e; 
}
```

I can't seem to display or use `e` for some reason. `Item` is on object that contains `Name` and `Price` and I would like to display the price on the second input.

Comment: `StateHasChanged();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just miss to cast e.Value to an int;

the below samples does what you wanted.

```
<select @onchange="DoStuff">
        <option value="0">A</option>
        <option value="1">B</option>
    </select>

<div class="d-none d-sm-block col-2">
    <input type="number" @bind-value="ItemQuantity"/>
</div>
<h1>Selected Value is: @ItemQuantity</h1>

@code{
    int ItemQuantity;


    private void DoStuff(ChangeEventArgs obj)
    {
        if (obj.Value is null) return;

        int.TryParse(obj.Value.ToString(), out var v);
        ItemQuantity = v;
    }
}
```